# Let $p$, $q$ be prime numbers, $p \neq q$. Find a natural number $n$ with $0 \neq n < pq$ such that $p^{2q−1} + q^{2p−1} \equiv n \pmod {pq}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$, $q$ be prime numbers, $p \neq q$. Find a natural number $n$ with $0 \neq n < pq$ such that $p^{2q−1} + q^{2p−1} ≡ n $(mod $pq)$.

So I figured out that $p^{2q−1} = p$ mod $q$ and $q^{2p−1} = q$ mod $p$.

Why does adding $p$ mod $q$ and $q$ mod $p$ = $p+q$ mod $pq$ ? My question, and this is probably very basic, is where does the mod $pq$ come from? Why does adding these two values together result in something which is modulo to the product of their moduli?

Comment: Isn't this just $n\equiv p\pmod q$ and $n\equiv q\pmod p$? Then Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: It's probably Fermats Little Theorem you mean.

Comment: I have to use Fermat's Little Theorem too but the (2q-1) is confusing me. Shouldn't it be just q-1 for Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: It should, but $2q-1$ isn't so far away from $q-1$. Try to obtain the $q-1$ somehow.

Comment: $2q-1=2(q-1)+1$.

Comment: Ahah. I see why the above statement was wrong

Comment: I see that $p^{2q -1} = p$ mod $q$ and $q^{2p -1} = q$ mod $p$.  What can I do from here? How would you apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: So the sum is congruent to $p+q$ modulo $p$ and modulo $q$. Chinese Remainder Theorem not needed, except in a very weak sense.

Comment: Why does adding $p$ mod $q$ and $q$ mod $p$ = $ p + n$ mod $pq$ ?
My question, and this is probably very basic, is where does the mod $pq$ come from? Why does adding these two values together result in something which is modulo to the product of their moduli?

Comment: You saw that $p^{2q-1}\equiv p\pmod{q}$. And trivially $q^{2p-1}\equiv q\pmod{q}$. So the sum is congruent to $p+q$ modulo $q$. So if the sum is $x$, then $q$ divides $x-(p+q)$. Similarly, $p$ divides $x-(p+q)$. So $pq$ divides $x-(p+q)$, and therefore $x\equiv p+q\pmod{pq}$.